# Scrollview Height Changes when Alert Controller is presented

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a scrollview with an image and text. The scrollview correctly displays its height encapsulating the image and text. When an alert controller is presented to the screen and dismissed, the scrollview's height changes. Any thoughts on why this happens and how to fix this?

[image]

View heirarchy before alert is presented:

[image]

After alert is presented:

[image]

The view is added after viewDidLoad and programmatically using constraints:

```
let offlineView = OfflineView()
view.addSubview(offlineView)
offlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
offlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
offlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
offlineView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
offlineView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

OfflineView Xib constraints:

[image]

Comment: Do you play with frame/contentSize ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan No, the view is Initialized from a xib and attached with constraints.

Comment: show xib constraints and where you add this view ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Added xib constraints. I add this view after viewDidLoad. No matter where I call the alert controller, this error occurs.

Comment: @Mocha - give your views contrasting background colors to make it easier to see the hierarchy. It looks like you have a lot of views layered on top of each other, or your views are subviews of other views when maybe they shouldn't be?

Comment: @DonMag I just showed the hierarchy to show the height gets changed for the scrollView. This page has two layers of views (I am showing an "Offline" view on top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My label in the scrollview constraints were Center X axis and Static width.

When I changed the label constraints to leading to superview = 45, trailing to superview >= 45, the error no longer persisted.

I don't know why/how this happened, but it fixed my problem.. If anyone could explain this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be weird. But you can give the below solution a try:

You are directly adding a UIScrollView to the main view. Instead, you should take one container view on main view and then add your scrollView on to that view and attach the constraints to that container view. And that container view should have the constraints wrt main view. This will solve your problem.

Comment: The scrollview is constrained to the xib view, not the main view

Comment: I know, but in general practice, we should give a container view to scrollView before adding scrollview directly to main view. container view will have the constraints with main view similar to what you want it to be with scrollview. And then scrollview will have constraints with container view, left, top, right and bottom constraints. You can just give it a try.